¿como conectar componentes livewire que estan en diferentes vistas?
Hellos comunidad, estoy desarrollando una aplicación web con Laravel 11 y Livewire 3, es sobre gestión de ventas en restaurante, tengo una vista que es sobre los platos, ahí en cliente  podrá hacer su pedido desde un componente Livewire, y estoy intentando que al momento que se envié ese pedido desde la vista del cocinero se actualice y muestre que se ha realizado un nuevo pedido.
Hasta ahorita solo e hecho pruebas y es así estoy emitiendo un evento:
class SolicitarPedidosWeb extends Component
{
    public $platos;
    
    public function mount(){
        $this->platos = Plato::select(
            "platos.id",
            "platos.NombrePlato",
            "platos.Descripcion",
            "platos.Precio"
        )->get();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.pedidos.solicitar-pedidos-web');
    }

    public function registrar(){
        $this->dispatch('click-agregar');
    }
}

Y para emitir el evento lo hago desde un clic de un botón que se estan generando dentro de unas card que son los plantos que estan disponibles y esta en la ruta "/":

<button class="btn btn-light mt-3 border border-danger agregar-carrito" wire:click="registrar()">
    <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> Agregar
</button>

y dentro del siguiente componente estoy intentado capturarlo:
class MostrarPedidos extends Component
{
    public $total = 0;

    
    public function render()
    {
        $pedidos = Pedido::all();
        
        return view('livewire.pedidos.mostrar-pedidos', compact('pedidos'));
    }
    
    #[On('click-agregar')]
    public function getTotal(){
       $this->total++;
    }
}


para mostrar lo estoy haciendo asi y se recibe en la ruta "/pedidos":
<p>{{ $total }}</p>

y no se como hacer para que esa variable $total se actualice y se muestre en la vista de mi componente
esto solo es una prueba para ver si mis 2 componentes se pueden comunicar y actualizar dinámicamente para crear métodos mas complejos
Muchas gracias por su tiempo

Solo por las dudas. Parece una obviedad, pero fíjate si los componentes están funcionando a la vez, O sea que los componentes tiene que cargarse en en la misma pagina o en la misma plantilla. para que funcionen los mensajes entre si.
Si ese el el caso , deberías ver si realmente recibe el mensaje el componente MostrarPedidos  .
En la función getTotal()  podrías poner un dd() con algún mensaje. Para asegurarte de que el dispatch funciona realmente y que el componente recibe el mensaje.
Si el componente recibe el mensaje, es una cosa y hay que ver como sigue.
Si no recibes el mensaje o el dd no sale ,fijate en la consola de desarrolladores a ver si tienes algún error referido a livewire o a otra cosa.
